Why is wavelet spectrogram didn't give ideal linear line from linear chirp?
Given linear chirp signal ranging from t0=4 and t1=6, the f0=2 represent frequency at t0 and f1=8 represent frequency at t1. Frequency unit is Hz and Time unit is Second and Amplitude unit is Volt, sample rate is 1000.

I converted time domain chirp into time-frequency domain (spectrogram) through convolution operation between chirp and morlet, then I find the global maxima at what time is the amplitude is max over frequency (line green):
It's linear, but it's not ideal linear, why?
Here is my code:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1b4erF_MM3ypY2hpkOwjQa4vLR36Td7An#scrollTo=pvmncId6GCUx


For one, a classic chirp signal should have the same absolute amplitude across the entire pulse. This has some kind of envelope that will change how the spectrum appears.
